# blood wall translation

Tags: translation

Can someone translate this text for me? I think I kinda understand it, but thinking about it deeper, I am not very sure.

[image]

Comment: Just in case, this is not written with blood

Answer (score 2):

```
Husband, husband, I am in Guangdong.
Working during the day, and arbeite in the night.
Forty yuan for thirty minutes.
```

This is a 打油诗. The speaker is a married woman, who has left her home and husband to work in another place. She does her  job in the day and becomes a sex worker in the night. And 40 yuan for half an hour is the charge for sex service since 80 yuan per hour is too high for a normal job. Here Guangdong infers Dongguan(东莞) in Guangdong province, which is famous of sex industry and titled the sex city of China. But of course Guangdong is a province that offers a lot of work opportunities and attracts many Chinese to leave home and work there.

Comment: What's *arbeite*?

Comment: @congusbongus it's a German word, *arbeiten*, to work. *arbeite* means `I work` or `I am working`. I just could not find a proper single word for `having part-time job` since my English vocabulary is limited. Though arbeite is not exactly `I am having part-time job`, I know a Japanese word `アルバイト`, *a ru ba i to*, which comes from `arbeiten` and means `having part-time job`,  so I just borrowed this word.

Answer (score 1):

1. O my dear husband, in Canton now I dwell.
2. I work By day, but with an easy virtue I earn by night.
3. For 40 dollars will I be paid, for 30 minutes will he be served.

开工 here means starting her sex business with men and by so she gets money.

Comment: why 开工 means that thing? Could it be for 30 minutes of babysitting, she get paid 40 dollars? especially when she wrote this poem while thinking about her husband.

Comment: It's just a metaphor here, you can't take it literally, I agree that your interpretation does make sense, but here It's not talking about babysitting, only about sex business, anyway here you need to know some culture background than the grammar itself, it's, just a metaphor :)

I agree with the explanation on the background given by @ElpieKay, you may take a look so that you understand it better.